# OpenCV python to java

Tags: java, android, python, opencv

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/) and I want to use it in my Android application. I have converted the code up to line 60 and I want to know how to use `M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(rect, dst)` in OpenCV Java.

The `dst` is a `np array`

```
dst = np.array([
    [0, 0],
    [maxWidth - 1, 0],
    [maxWidth - 1, maxHeight - 1],
    [0, maxHeight - 1]], dtype = "float32")
```

and I have no idea what datatype I should use in my Java code.

Comment: [`Mat`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#getPerspectiveTransform(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat)), presumably.

Comment: But what should the dimensions and type of the Mat be?

Comment: 4 rows, 2 columns, by the looks of it. It's representing the xy coordinates of the 4 corners.

Comment: For Mat there is also a type required. What should the type be? CvType.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the given link, a numpy array of 4x1 dimensions is being created of dtype = float32. So This can also be done in Java as:

```
Mat dst = new Mat(4, 1, CvType.CV_32FC2);
```

The above snippet creates a 2-channel `Mat` with 4 rows and 1 column, to accommodate the 4 points having 2 dimensions(x and y).

Comment: I am still a little confused. If we have 2 dimensions (x, y), why do we only need 1 column. Shouldn't it be 2?

Comment: Basically here we have a `4 x 1 x 2` matrix, the 4 and 1 come from number and columns and rows, the 2 comes from `CV_32FC2`. So it defines a 4 x 1 matrix with 2 channels which is same as defining a 4 x 1 x 2 matrix